# How to fix "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'East'" (Python)

Tags: python

When the user enters "East" I want the output to be -1 not "East"

```
East = -1

Xdirectioninput = float(input("Is the player South or East: "))
Xdirectioninput = (Xdirectioninput)

print (Xdirectioninput)
```

Comment: So write a function that converts the input. You can't just cast it to `float` and expect it to work

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to coding! I will start doing my research on functions now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will only work in Python 2. It works because in Python 2, what the user types in response to `input()` is evaluated as a Python expression.

But you can't do that in Python 3. One way to do it is to set up a dictionary with directions:

```
directions = {"East": -1.0, "South": -2.0}
Xdirectioninput = directions[input("Is the player South or East: ")]
```

Answer (score 0):

I  think conditional statement would be good solution. You could make a code as follows:

```
Xdirectioninput = input("Is the player South or East: ")
if Xdirectioninput == 'East':
    Xdirection = -1
print(Xdirection)
```